# Where are .po translations supposed to go?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have .po file with translation and I have it in modulename/translation/xy.po

When I installed profile in XY language the file was not loaded.
I did a little digging and found that \FileTranslation::getTranslationFilesPattern looks for drupal-8.xy.po pattern so I renamed the file, reinstalled my profile but the language still was not picked up. The interface translation was downloaded just fine though. If I manually import the file it works. So it looks to me like the directory for translations has changed maybe?

---

I have checked the installer and it looks like Drupal only looks into the site's files/translations directory. So how are modules supposed to ship with translations?

---

So it looks like the translations ARE being imported just fine(entries are present in the locales_source table), but for some reason not everything is displayed translated.

---

Ok, so I came to a conclusion that my translation file is not imported at all. The reason for incomplete translation is because it comes from downloaded Drupal localization and not my file. I am looking at installer and there is nothing that would suggest po files discovery mechanism in any way, only the drupal core(or any po file) in the files/translations directory(which is where the drupal translation is downloaded into).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it looks like this change https://www.drupal.org/node/1352228 is cause of all the hell with translations. I'm not sure how I'll handle this for multisite but at least I know where the issue came from.

---

As a follow-up in order for local .po files to be used one needs to add new records into module's info file or implement the hook_locale_translation_projects_alter. The description of this hook basically explains everything.

But still, it is not working. I had to manually run locale_system_update(array('module' => array('mymodule'))); and CC'd afterwards in order for the translation file to be successfully imported and used. I am not sure if this is a bug or not but it is a huge PITA.

I need the translation to work when the site is installed(I have custom profile) so I have to implement this as additional installation task but am not sure if it will work sin in the locale_system_update function it says not to do this while installing. If anyone has figured this thing out, please leave an answer or a comment, thanks.

---

**Final solution:** I had to create two additional installation steps in my profile. Basically I have split the locale_system_update() since it defines two batches. I am running them as last two steps so install_finished() runs before them.

One more info: I had to replace the locale_translation_batch_update_build with manually importing the file since it was not working as expected. So now in my first step I will import desired .po files(see \Drupal\locale\Form\ImportForm::submitForm()) and in the seconds step I am updating config translation since installation handler cannot handle multiple batch configurations even if it says it does(maybe it is not working only in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the directory sites/default is writable, so that during installation the translation files can be copied to the translations directory at sites/default/files/translations